# Problems with logging/redirecting in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

using this code I've countered a bit of a problem. When I try to redirect to subfolder it ignores registered user and redirects me back to index.php site.

```
// auth.php
class myAuth {
    static function checkAuth() {
        // detect user by set cookie
        // and value which we saved in session
        if(!session_id()) session_start();
        // check ...
        if(
            isset($_COOKIE["auth"])
            &&
            isset($_SESSION["auth"])
            &&
            $_COOKIE["auth"] == $_SESSION["auth"]
        ) {
            // extend the session and cookie and in mysql as well
            self::_setCookieSessionDBTokenValidity();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } // chechAuth finish

    // this funkcion redirect user
    // on main site (index.php)
    // na početnu stranicu (index.php)
    // use checkAuthWithRedirect if he's not logged in
    static function checkAuthWithRedirect() {
        if(!self::checkAuth()) {
            header('Location:index.php');
        }
    } // checkAuthWithRedirect finish
static function doLogin() {
    // register user
    // save data in session
    if(
        !empty($_POST['user'])
        &&
        !empty($_POST['pass'])
    ) {
        if(!session_id()) session_start();

        // chech and fetch data for user with sended pass
        $user = self::_fetchUserWithPassDB();


        // if we find user finish login
        if($user) {
            // strengthen pass a bit

            $token = md5(rand(100000,999999));

            // save token in session
            $_SESSION["auth"] = $token;

            // save user in session
            $_SESSION["user"] = $user[0]["user"];

            // save role in session
            $_SESSION["role"] = $user[0]["role"];

            // postavi validity i token u cookie, session i bazu
            // save validity and token in cookie, session in db
            self::_setCookieSessionDBTokenValidity();                   

            // redirect 
            header("Location:admin.php");

        }
        else {

            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">';
            p('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>      USER DOES NOT EXIST!');
            echo '</div>';
        }


    } 

} // login
```

This block of code works fine when redirect me to site which is in root folder but when I try to redirect to subfolder it completily ignores code and redirects me to index.php.

Example:

```
            // redirect 
            header("Location:test/admin.php");
```

And here is example of admin.php site

```
<?php
// login.php
require_once(__DIR__.'/init.php');
showHTMLHeaderWithTitle('Prijava');
myAuth::checkAuthWithRedirect();
?>


<h1>TEST TEST TEST</h1>



<?php
showHTMLFooter();
?>
```

Comment: you sure you're not getting a 404 here? if `test` isn't  a sub-folder of the script's execution location, then go back to the root `header("Location:/test/admin.php"); exit;` or a full http call `header("Location: http://www.example.com/test/admin.php"); exit;` - check for errors also.

Comment: you also tagged as `.htaccess` so we don't know if you've a bad rewrite. Again, check for errors or look at your logs, should there be something in there. I for one will not be able to pop in a magic answer; good luck. I will pass on this one and move on.

Comment: .htaccess was my tag fail. Never mind, I posted question while searching for answer myself. Thank you for you time. I ll look for errors

Answer (score 0):

Replace header functions parameter - "**static function checkAuthWithRedirect()**" in auth.php with the following

```
static function checkAuthWithRedirect() {
        if(!self::checkAuth()) {
            header('Location:test/admin.php');
        }
    }
```

It is because, when you place redirect to test/admin.php in doLogin() within auth.php,

> the **myAuth::checkAuthWithRedirect();** in *admin.php* initiates **checkAuthWithRedirect()** in *auth.php* where it is again redirecting to *index.php*

Just replace the redirect value in **checkAuthWithRedirect()** to test/admin.php & redirect value in **doLogin()** to test/admin.php. It would work!

Comment: I tried to do that before and it doesn't work it creates following URL which is incorrect : **test/test/admin.php** and I need to redirect me to this URL **test/admin.php**. To be fair _function checkAuth()_ is used to create verification on site. _If the user is not logged in redirect him to index.php_ But I do appreciate your effort, thank you kind sir!